# Fetching the website version number from the database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I was just writing some code the other day, and I found myself writing something I am not sure whether it is OK to do it like this, or not.

Let me give an example of what this is:

I have this Method:

```
    public static string STOLENVersion()
    {
        string version = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("SELECT TOP 1");
            sb.AppendLine("    [WebsiteVersion]");
            sb.AppendLine("FROM [WebsiteDefaults]");
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), NewSQLConnection))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                version = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                cmd.Connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return "Version: " + version;
    }
```

And I have this property:

```
public static SqlConnection NewSQLConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DebugDB"].ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

I am disposing the SqlCommand's connection inside its using block, and this method can be called multiple times (maybe like 10 times every minute, as users log on to the website, as an example)

Comment: Is this code being run from a utility program, or your actual website?

Comment: From my actual website :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `try-catch-throw` with no error handling is completely pointless. I would just remove it and let the exception bubble up the call stack.
- There is no need to call `connection.Dispose()` since the `using () { ... }` block will do that automatically
- A StringBuilder object is like hitting a thumbtack with a sledge hammer in this case. You can prefix a string literal with the `@` symbol to allow newline characters for better readibility:

  ```
  string sql = @"SELECT TOP 1
                 [WebsiteVersion]
                 FROM [WebsiteDefaults]";
  ```

  Or since this is such a simple SQL statement, a one-liner is appropriate as well:

  ```
  string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 [WebsiteVersion] FROM [WebsiteDefaults]";
  ```

Comment: Or you can use string concatenation `string sql = "SELECT TOP 1"+" [WebsiteVersion] "+" FROM [WebsiteDefaults]";` and compiller is quite smart to perform it at compile time.   (sadly that comments on this site don't allow line-breaks)

Comment: So, disposing the "SqlCommand" will also dispose the SqlConnection?

Comment: That's a good question. To be honest, I always create the SqlConnection object in its own `using` statement to ensure it gets garbage collected properly.  @Greg already mentioned that in his answer.

Comment: I see. Nah I'll just add the SqlConnection with a using block then :). Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would see the following:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {

    }
```

The reason, you wouldn't have to worry about forgetting to close the connection.  Which could introduce congruency issues.

However, your approach is fine assuming other developers don't open a connection that is already open, or close a connection that isn't closed already.